# How to get auto increment work on NAVICAT

Tags: mysql, primary-key, increment, navicat

I am using NAVICAT to make tables for MYSQL and I am unable to find the auto-increment attribute option for my primary key column.

```
id integer(10)(auto_increment)primary key
```

Anyone pls help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with NAVICAT but if you can run SQL statements directly, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `yourTable` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Full docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 2):

As reported there is an auto increment checkbox in Navicat, but you have to create an integer key before, save the operation, and reselect the field, now on the bottom area the auto increment checkbox will appear.

Answer (score 1):

**click on key at the end of field, and it makes visible Auto increment option**

[image: Navicat auto increment]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Navicat (10.1.0 Mac) Enterprise. In the table creation dialog, there is a checkbox for `auto increment` which should do the thing that you are looking for.